# Какой вариант разметки правильный?

Tags: css, html5

Есть шаблон на Figma -> [Шаблон](https://www.figma.com/file/IOvJLHLLyKmYH2gZTJPhKm/MNTN-Landing-Page?node-id=1%3A2)

Обучаюсь тому как пишет автор на ютубе.
Обращаем внимание на Footer.

Автор задает небольшую анимацию с помощью контента(полоски снизу под ссылкой) и у него выходит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст "Privacy Policy" находится не на одном уровне с "Copyright", который слева, но в сумме с полоской на одном.

Мой же вариант:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Весь текст на уровне, лишь полоска выходит за пределы блока.

Какой вариант должен быть? Если вариант автора, то почему?(он же нарушает дизайн, созданный на figma)

Comment: текст должен быть на одной линии. Подчеркивания, изменения цвета и всякие эффекты должны оговариваться или с дизайнером, или с заказчиком. Часто дизайнер сам указывает как должен выглядеть элемент в фокусе

Comment: @sanya-h как в этом случае будет более верно?

Comment: автор допустил ошибку